# send POST with httprequest to php

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

I want to send a random number to an xml-file with http request and php.
But i cant really figure out how to add the value of the generated number and add it to the post.

This is what i have so far.

```
var x=document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
x[x.length-1].innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000)+1);
// Generates a random number and print it on the last demo class

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
  //  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","/project3/php/update.php",true); //Calls the php update file
xmlhttp.send();
```

PHP file

```
<?php 
       $dom = new DOMDocument();
       $dom->load('../stickers.xml');
       $stickers = $dom->documentElement;
       $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
       $result = $xpath->query('/stickers/sticker[id="$POST"]/id'); //Not sure.
       $result->item(0)->nodeValue .= 'hi';
       echo $dom->saveXML();
       $dom->save('../stickers.xml');

?>
```

Comment: Any reason to not use JQuery with `$.Post()`?

Comment: xmlhttp.open("GET","/project3/php/update.php?update="+x[x.length-1].innerHTML,true);

Comment: @sdespont well, yes its for studying purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get` method sends parameters as a query string in the URL, whereas the `post` query string is sent within the http headers:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","/project3/php/update.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("random="+x[x.length-1].innerHTML);
```

On the PHP side of things, posts variables are added to a global associative array like so:

```
<?php echo $_POST['random'];
```

Comment: Okej, I actually get a result now. but it seems like my query is still wrong. any idea ?

  $result = $xpath->query('/stickers/sticker'+ $_POST['random']+ '/id');

Comment: @Dymond what do you get when you `print_r($result)`?

Comment: Hi. sorry it was my fault, mixed the variables. Its working like a charm. was just about to write it :)

Thanks alot!

Comment: @Dymond glad you got it sorted :)